# Helm rollback commands rollback the entire release in sub-chart scenario

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Given a situation where we have Helm chart `A` which contains a sub-chart `B`. Let's perform below sequence of operations.

1. `helm install test /path/to/A` . It installs the sub-chart `B` as well under the same `Helm release` name i.e. `test`
2. Do some configuration changes that impacts both the charts. e.g. change some env variables.
3. Do `helm upgrade test /path/to/A` . Upgrades all the affected pods under chart `A` and `B`
4. Due to some reasons, I want to just rollback the new changes done on `sub-chart B` but keep the new changes on `A`.
5. Do `helm rollback test`.

Now, the step 5th rollbacks the chart `A` changes as well. Now, the question is, Can I restrict the rollback just to chart `B` ? Is it possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.  The parent chart `A` and the subchart `B` are parts of the same Helm release once they're installed, and you can only upgrade or roll back the entire release, not fragments of it.

If you keep your deployment configuration in source control, you could do a partial revert of your per-environment configuration file the same way you'd do a partial revert of any other file, and then `helm upgrade` again to the "new" (partially-reverted) configuration.